# For a function $f: X \to Y$, if $Y-V$ is finite, when is $X - f^{-1}(V)$ finite?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I apologize if this is a silly question but I just do not know enough set theory (i.e., sizes) to understand if it's even silly.

My question is

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function of sets. Suppose $V \subset Y$, and that $Y - V$ is finite (countable). Is $X - f^{-1}(V)$ finite (countable)? What conditions do we need to place on $f$ to guarantee it will be finite (countable)?

So I kind of have two questions. But I will take either.

**Why I care:**

I'm asking this because I want to know the following. Recall that for a set $X$, we can endow $X$ with the **finite complement topology** where a set $U \subset X$ is open if $X - U$ is finite. Denote this topology on a set $X$ as $FC_X$.

Now suppose $f: X \to Y$ is a function. As $X$ and $Y$ are sets, we may ask:

> Does the function $f: X \to Y$ extend to a continuous function $f: (X, FC_X) \to (Y, FC_Y)$?

For such a function to be continuous, we need that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open if $U$ is open. In this case, that means that if $Y - U$ is finite then $X - f^{-1}(U)$ must be finite. But I do not know when that last statement holds, and hence it's my question above. My guess is that if $f$ is injective, then it will be true, but I don't really know if that's true. I lack the set theory knowledge to really attack such a problem.

Finally, if the above answer is true, it tells me that I've got a functor $F: \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Top}$ where $X$ is sent to the finite complement topology. I'm also interested in the countable case, since that would give me another different functor. But that's besides the question.

Comment: This isn't true in general. Consider the case where $X$ is infinite, $Y$ is finite (and $V$ is empty).

Comment: You want the preimage of finite subsets to be finite. This is equivalent to the preimage of each point being finite. So you don't actually need $f$ to be 1-1, it is enough for it to be "finite to 1".

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. I need to have only at most finitely many $x\in X$ "hit" each $y \in Y$?

Comment: Picking up from the comment of user Cronus above, maybe it's worth noting that sets and finite-to-one maps constitute a category, so at least you get a functor from that category to $\mathbf{Top}$.

Comment: Oh because their composition is also finite to one, and the identity is finite to one too. This then gives me an example of a non-functor which becomes a functor upon fixing the domain category. Thanks!

Comment: Also, no offence, but I would caution against the attitude "I lack the set theory knowledge to really attack such a problem". This question didn't need any familiarity with set theory (hence why the tags were edited) or other specialized prereqs. Resolving it was just a matter of deploying (or developing) critical thinking skills which are essential in every part of math. Rather than have "excused yourself" because of a perceived lack of prereqs, you'd have been better off trying to decide for yourself what was "really going on", maybe drawing dots and arrows on a piece of paper as an aid.

Comment: $X=Y=\mathbb R,\quad V=\mathbb R\setminus\{1,2,3\},\quad f(1)=2,f(2)=3,f(3)=1, f(x)=x$ otherwise. 

Then $f(V)=\mathbb R\setminus\{1,2,3\}$ and $X\setminus f^{-1}=\{1,2,3\}$

Comment: @MikeF None taken, I see what you're saying and I don't like wasting people's time with trivial questions. When I initially thought about this I thought it had to do with the size of sets $X$ and $Y$ relative to each other. Realizing I know nothing about sizes of sets, and knowing that it additionally gets complicated because you also have to specify what set theory you're really talking about, I figured it'd be good to ask here.

Comment: @trujello: OK that makes sense. Your intuition led you to believe there were set-theoretic issues at stake, but that turned out not to be the case. Nothing wrong with that at all! :)

Comment: @trujello While I don't think you've wasted anyone's time, I would it is a good advice to never assume a problem is too difficult for you/requires knowledge you don't have. It often seems to us this is the case while it isn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Cronus in the comments, it is sufficient that $f$ has the property that the preimage of every point is a finite set. I believe it is also a necessary condition.

Let's just consider surjective functions, just for convenience (it really doesn't change anything since any function $f:X \to Y$ can be 'made surjective' by replacing its codomain with its image.)

To see that the condition is sufficient, note that if some $f: X \to Y$ has the property, then for finite $Y \setminus V$,
$$ X \setminus f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(Y \setminus V) = \bigcup_{y \in Y \setminus V} f^{-1}(y).$$
In other words, $X \setminus f^{-1}(V)$ is the union of a finite number of finite sets.

I believe this condition is also necessary, and here is a proof that seems to be correct. Assume that $f$ doesn't have the property, and thus there exists some $y$ with $f^{-1}(y)$ not finite. Taking $V = Y \setminus \{ y \}$, one then concludes that
$$ X \setminus f^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(y),$$
which is not finite. Importantly, we have that $f^{-1}(V)$ does not intersect $f^{-1}(y)$ since no $x \in X$ can be mapped both into $V$ and into $\{ y \}$. Thus by contradiction we have that $f$ must have the finite-to-one property.

Comment: This is great! It was the next thing I was wondering but you've worked it out already Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be an infinite set, $Y$ a finite set and $V = \emptyset$. Then for any function $f : X \to Y$ we have that $Y\setminus V = Y$ is finite but $X \setminus f^{-1}(V) = X$ is infinite.

We get a similar conclusion for your other question if $X$ is an uncountable set and $Y$ is a countable set.